# How can I get access to user identity after callback in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

in my controller I have this below behaviour function:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'verifym'  => ['OPTIONS','POST','GET']
            ]
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => [
                        'index', 'payment', 'result', 'verify',
                        'paymentvalidation'
                    ],
                    'roles' => [ 'user' ]
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['verifym'],
                    'roles' => ['*']
                ]
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                $this->redirect([ '/' ]);
                return null;
            }
        ]
    ];
}
```

When from outside referrer calls `verifym` action it not fires, and `denyCallBack` fires.
And user identity is null.

Why `denyCallBack` is fire and what change needs in my access rule for this?

Why user identity is null and How can access to that in callback process?

Why after callback from other different domain, user identity and sessions is null and with a refresh it take values?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems after calling back my url from other specific domain, it's blocked their headers in request and Yii framework identity checks some headers by reading them from request's header.
So I configured it by send and get some parameters between request and response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire for all users you have to set it like this (of all authenticated user):

```
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'actions' => ['verifym'],
                'roles' => ['@']
            ]
```

You can see the documentetion and examples - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol

Comment: ok, thank you I do it, But why after callback `Yii::$app->user->identity` is null and how can fill it before action?

Comment: My user identity is full. You have another error samowhere.

Comment: after callback from other different domain in the first line of my action I get user identity null but after refresh it has value

Comment: Are you logged in your system?

Comment: Yes I am logged in